# how to call new activity when user cuts incoming call from specific number

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to open new `activity` when user cuts incoming call from specific number .
I know I have to use `TelephonyManager` and `PhoneStateListener` to listen different kinds of state of call .
I also tried below example but it opens `activity` more than one time I want to open only once. kindly help me

```
public class Demos extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) 
         return;        
    else
    {
         final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
         PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
         {
             public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
                     {       
                 if((state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING))
                 {  }
                 if((state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                 {  }
                 if(!(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) && (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) )
                 {
                     if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("XXX-XXX-XXXX"))
                     {  Intent i=new Intent(context,Activity_two.class);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(i);
                                telephonyManager.listen(null,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); }
                 }
                    }
         }; telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)  
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't scale down if you don't know right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below code along with your phone number check

```
        final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                Log.e("CALL STATE", state + "");
                if(!(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) && (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) )
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Activity opens more than one time happens while your application is in foreground. Right? If so, try checking by adding android:launchMode="singleTask" attribute to the activity.

Comment: i think my code is already work but i jut have to add android:launchMode="singleTask" by the way thank you for support